# Q: Displaying server (re)start and/or refresh time in client. (Nearly works)

Tags: meteor

I want to display the server restart time in the client.  Something like:

```
<body>Server started at {{serverStartTime}}</body>
```

which is serviced by a helper:

```
Template.body.helpers({
    serverStartTime: function(){
      Meteor.call("getServerStartTime",function(err,res){
          Session.set('sStartTime',res);  //ignore errors
        }          
      });
      return Session.get('sStartTime');
    }
});
```

Note the Session.get() is tracker bait for the Session.set() in the same function, it isn't meant to be executed synchronously after Meteor.call().

To get the server start time we have

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function(){
    Meteor.ServerStartTime = new Date();
  }); 
}
Meteor.methods({
  getServerStartTime: function(){
    var sst = Meteor.ServerStartTime;
    if(sst){
      console.log(Meteor.ServerStartTime);  // for info
      return sst.toLocaleTimeString();
    }  
  }
});
```

This works in a fashion but:

(a) Having the helper act recursively makes me feel dirty. Nightmare possibility of infinite loop.

(b) It picks up *restart* (ie when js is changed) but not *refreshing* (ie
   when only html is changed).

I'm new to Meteor.  Is there a simpler, safer, clearer way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the infinite-loop possibility, you could just move the method call outside of the helper, so it runs once when the page is loaded:

```js
Meteor.call("getServerStartTime", function (err, res) {
    Session.set('sStartTime', res);        
});

Template.body.helpers({
    serverStartTime: function () {
        return Session.get('sStartTime')
    }
});
```

To solve the refresh problem (where the client's value doesn't refresh when the server restarts without triggering a browser refresh), you could instead use a custom publish function. I tested this in a [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/EZ3h2BK42k2YNqBc6/Leaderboard). In the server:

```js
var startupTime = new Date();

Meteor.publish("startupTime", function () {
  this.added("startupTime", "startupTime", {startupTime: startupTime});
  this.ready();
});
```

And in the client:

```js
var StartupTime = new Mongo.Collection("startupTime");
var startupTimeSub = Meteor.subscribe("startupTime");
```

Then you can get the server startup time reactively using `StartupTime.findOne().startupTime` (assuming the subscription is ready, which you can test reactively with `startupTimeSub.ready()`). When the server reloads, the value will update even if the client didn't have to refresh (e.g. you only changed server-side code).

To the client, this looks like the server has a mongo collection called `startupTime`, containing a single document `{_id: "startupTime", startupTime: <date>}`. But in reality the collection doesn't exist.